# All files suddenly became read only, the reboot halts : (

Tags: ssd, reboot

I was in the middle of working on something, and my files suddenly became read only. I couldn't open a browser. I rebooted, then got stuck on this screen (diagnostics on):

```
Please unlock disk sda3_crypt:

[ 15.138216] NET: Registered protocol family 38 WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.

Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while... Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type 1vm2 WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning. 2 logical volume (s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active cryptsetup (sda3_crypt): set up successfully

done. Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount done. Begin: Will now check root file system fsck from util-linux 2.31.1

[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root] fsck.ext4 -a -CO /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root contains a file system with errors, check forced. Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options) fsck exited with status code 4

done.

Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) [ 17.891055] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: stopping RX ring 0

[

[

17.891847] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200

17.892710] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: stopping TX ring 0 17.893492] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200

[ 17.894282] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: control channel stopped
```

Comment: The error messages indicate that the file system contains errors, and that you should manually run fsck against the system to try and repair those errors.  Have you done that?  I would assume that to do this, you would need to boot from a live USB, and run something like `sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`

Comment: That did the trick. Took a lot of wrangling, but the machine appears to be working just fine and a quick hardware diagnostic shows nothing wrong. I'm worried though : /

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.  It does happen that there are errors on the disk that force a ro remount - this can be a problem with the encrypted disks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages indicate that the file system contains errors, and that you should manually run fsck against the system to try and repair those errors.

you would need to boot from a live USB, and run something like

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

Following that, assuming it was successful, you might investigate your disk health using the [smart tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools), and of course, maintain a backup of your data

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing. Just took a few matrix screens and a few reboots after that. I ran a hardware diagnostic that said everything checked out, but should I be worried?

Comment: @CostaMichailidis I've had similar disk errors on an older computer - I would enable the [smart disk tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) on your computer, if your disk supports them, and see if there's anything there.  Also, keep a backup of your data...